# Regex number match

Tags: regex

How can I get a match when numbers are 5 or 7 digits long with these parameters?

[image]

Comment: Attaching image doesn't make it a question

Comment: Enclose with `\b`s.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, [this (visualize here)](https://regex101.com/r/yU2bU3/1) should do it:

```
`/\b([5-9]\d{4}(?:\d{2})?)\b/`
```